# How do you get the Finder “Kind” for a file, in 2016?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan, launch-services

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20506006) says to use LSCopyKindStringForURL(), which has worked great in the past, but it's marked "deprecated" in OS X v10.11.

There's no mention in the API documentation of why it was deprecated.  I don't see any mention of Launch Services API changes in the OS X 10.11 release notes at all.

How are you supposed to get the Finder Kind of a file now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you go to the declaration of `LSCopyKindStringForURL()` in the header (`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Headers/LSInfoDeprecated.h`), you'll find in the comment and the deprecation attribute, the following:

> Use the URL resource property kCFURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey or NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey instead.

These are resource keys for use with `CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey()` or `-[NSURL getResourceValue:forKey:error:]`, respectively.